# Trouble implementing Error Exceptions in Java Spring

Tags: java, spring, maven, exception, feign

I'm new to using SpringBoot.
I have implemented a FeignClient for my microservice "cars" for the RequestMapping and now I need to do the same for the Exception handling.

**CarClient.java**

```
@FeignClient("cars")
public interface CarClient {
    String api = "cars";
    
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = api + "/", produces = "application/JSON")
    ResponseEntity<List<Car>> getAllCars();

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = api + "/{id}", produces = "application/JSON")
    ResponseEntity<Car> findByCarId(@PathVariable("id") Long carId, Car car);
}
```

**CarController.java**

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
public class CarController implements CarClient {

    @Autowired
    private CarService carService;

    public ResponseEntity<List<Car>> getAllCars() {
        try {
            log.info("Returning a list of the cars.");
            return new ResponseEntity<List<Car>>(carService.getAllCars(), HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        catch (NotExist ex) {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "The database is empty.", ex);
        }
    }

    public ResponseEntity<Car> findByCarId(Long carId, Car car) {
        try {
            log.info("Returning the carId.");
            return new ResponseEntity<Car>(carService.findCarById(carId), HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        catch (NotExist ex) {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "Sorry, this ID was not found.", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

**CarService.java**

```
@Slf4j
@Service
public class CarService {

    @Autowired
    private CarRepository carRepository;

    public List<Car> getAllCars() throws NotExist{
        if (carRepository.findAll().isEmpty()) throw new NotExist("There are no cars in the database.");

        log.info("Success! Retrieving all {} cars.", carRepository.findAll().size());
        return carRepository.findAll();
    }

    public Car findCarById(long carId) throws NotExist {
        Car existingCar = carRepository.findById(carId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new NotExist("Sorry, the car was not found."));

        log.info("Success! The car {} was fetched.", existingCar.getLicensePlateNum());
        return carRepository.findByCarId(carId);
    }
}
```

I wish to move the exception handling from the **CarsController** to the **CarClient**.
How can I correct implement the code? Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Why create an interface with `@FeignClient` and next implement it... That doesn't make sense. Your service implementation isn't the beist either, why are you execution a query 3 times in the `findAll` and twice in the `findCarById`.

Comment: Oh is the @FeignClient("cars") not needed?

Comment: The Service implementation doesn't matter rn. I can improve it later. What I was wondering if how to implement the exception handling.

Comment: Again your interface + implementation doesn't make any sense... An interface with `@FeignClient` doesn't need an implementation, it is an interface and proxy for a remote system. So what you show here doesn't make sense. Regarding the exception handling that is what `@ExceptionHandler` is for.

Comment: The interface makes sense to me and works. Guess should try looking into @ExceptionHanlder more

Comment: I'm not saying it won't work, the combination of `@FeignClient` and an implemented interface doesn't make sense. Generally a controller with an interface is more trouble then it is worth.

Answer (score 0):

You want to mix up duties.

Feign Client CarClient provides you with a simple client class that executes CarController. It is just much more convenient than implementing it manually + includes support of load balancer paths.

Error handling is the responsibility of the controller. The controller accepts the request and returns an answer. Error handling is needed here to provide answers in depends on your logic execution status.

If you just want to make error handling more readable you can do smth like:

```java
@Slf4j
@RestController
public class CarController implements CarClient {

    @Autowired
    private CarService carService;

    public List<Car> getAllCars() throws EmptyDb {
         log.info("Returning a list of the cars.");
         return carService.getAllCars();
    }
    
    public Car findByCarId(Long carId, Car car) throws NotExist {
         log.info("Returning the carId.");
         return carService.findCarById(carId);
    }
    
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    @ExceptionHandler(EmptyDb.class)
    public ResponseStatusException handle(EmptyDb ex) {
        return new ResponseStatusException("The database is empty.");
    }
    
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStNotExistatus.NOT_FOUND)
    @ExceptionHandler(NotExist.class)
    public ResponseStatusException handle(NotExist ex) {
        return new ResponseStatusException("Sorry, this ID was not exists")
    }
}
```

@ExceptionHandler will return ResponseStatusException with a status of @ResponseStatus if your controller methods will throw NotExist or EmptyDb exceptions.

P.S. Consider that in general, your code needs more refactoring and work.